# CakePHP2-PHP8 - Tests with PHPUnit ^9.5

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I'm using CakePHP2-PHP8 version of this framework, which can be found on [this github](https://github.com/kamilwylegala/cakephp2-php8)

If someone can help me, I have problems with PHPUnit testing. Please correct me if I am doing something wrong, but
when i try to run Cake tests I found several problems. Let's use command from CakePHP Doc:

`Console/cake test app AllTests`

**Issue 1.**
First I receive an error from main test dispatcher file `/cakephp2-php8/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php` method `loadTestFramework`. Problem is that method try to check does class exist with old PHPUnit namespace in class name with underscores `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`. That is for older versions of PHPUnit (such as 4.*)

`line 152 - if (class_exists('PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase')) {...`

It is working when i replace old classname with this `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`.
That is the problem in multiple files, and on some places PHPUnit classnames are written ok with new namespace. So problem is in that mix where some files use new namespace with class name and some files use old style
I needed to replace all old namespaces with new one (approximate 65 times inside 13 files)
Here is the list of files:
[image]

**Issue 2.**
After all replaces, I found that some CakeTest classes extends `final` PHPUnit classes which cause an error. Than I edited my `vendor/phpunit` I removed `final` prefix in these classes:

```
Class CakeTestLoader cannot extend final class PHPUnit\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader in lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestLoader.php

Class CakeTestRunner cannot extend final class PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner in lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestCase.php
```

**Issue 3.**
Than I get error for method declaration which is not compatible with extended PHPUnit class methods inside `Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestCase.php`:

```
Declaration of CakeTestCase::setUp() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::setUp()

Declaration of CakeTestCase::tearDown() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::tearDown()
```

Here I also fix `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` instde `vendor/phpunit`.

---

After I fix all 3 issues my command for testing is working now `Console/cake test app AllTests`.

I think that this is not the right way to do because i made changes inside core framework files, and also changes inside vendor/phpunit directory.

Is there another way to run cake tests inside this framework?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: "I receive an error from main test dispatcher file" - can oyu share that error?

Comment: Also, if you are **really** still using CakePHP2, please update your application. The original maintainers declared that version EOL in 2021! PHPUnit 9 was released in 2020, so it's not surprising that CakePHP2 might not support it

Comment: Because of checking the class that does not exist `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` script try to load missing 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' [screenshoot](https://prnt.sc/nj8v18scNgco) We don't need autoload because if I correct classname, than class does exist

Comment: I am not using clean CakePHP2, I use [this](https://github.com/kamilwylegala/cakephp2-php8) custom version of Cake which (according to their documentation) it should work with PHPUnit 9.5 and on PHP8

Comment: i have very (very) large application written in old CakePHP2 (currently on php7.4) and there is no enough developers and no resources to change to Cake version 3 or 4, so I am forced to use Cake2